# Python cx_Oracle connection DLL error

Tags: python, dll, cx-oracle

I have configured the Oracle client and try with the below code, But error prompted from the code.

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_12_2")
import cx_Oracle
ORACLE_CONNECT = "user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(SOURCE_ROUTE=OFF)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sid)(SRVR=DEDICATED)))"
orcl = cx_Oracle.connect(ORACLE_CONNECT)
print("Connected to Oracle: " + orcl.version)
```

**Error :**
**Python.exe - Entry Point Not Found**

*The Procedure entry point K32GetModuleBaseNameA could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll*

I am using Server 2008 32 bit as client machine and remotely connect to Oracle Data Base 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit
Tried both Python 2.7 and 3.6.
Instant client version is "instantclient_12_2"

[image]

Appreciate if you can give me a feedback on this.

Thanks,
Tharindu Panagoda

Comment: Don't do the chdir: you should make sure that the Instant Client is in your PATH environment variable before you run python.  Also make sure you have the correct VS Redistributable - the Instant Client download page has the details.  Here are the installation instructions http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
I have fixed the code as you mentioned, instant client is configured correctly and the VS Redistributables are in place.I have checked from another PC which runs Windows 7 and code was worked perfectly. As I suspected there is some issue with Kernel32.dll in Windows 2008 Server..Is there any way to fix that or to update the DLL.